Disable transition animation effect between Views
I've beed looking everywhere for how to disable the transition effect when changing views in SwiftUI but none of the solutions work for me. Not even ChatGPT can help me. This is the part of the code:
struct TransfersView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ListView()
                BottomDockView()
                    .padding(.top, -8)
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Transfers")
        
    }
}

struct BottomDockView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MainView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 50)
                }

            }
            Spacer()
            Spacer()

            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: TransfersView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left.arrow.right")
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 50)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 60)
            }
            Spacer()
            Spacer()

            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: CryptoView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "bitcoinsign")
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 50)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 50)

            }
            Spacer()
        }        //dockButtons
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
        
    }
}

I want to press the buttons and take me to the view without any animations.
I've tried using animation(_:value:) and .transaction { transaction in print(transaction.animation) // Prints: nil when not animated.}, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is because you are using a NavigationView (which btw is deprecated, use a NavigationStack instead). If you don't want the animations, try using a ZStack instead and just switch view using a switch or if-else.

A NavigationView comes with animations and these cannot be disabled. So if you don't want a change of view to be animated, you probably need to look for a different way to switch views. Btw, NavigationView is deprecated, if your target is iOS 16 or above you should be using NavigationStack instead.
You seem to have some recursion in your example, because TransfersView contains BottomDockView, but one of the links in BottomDockView navigates to TransitionView. This is not a good idea.
If you just want to use a tab bar to switch views then a TabView provides an easy way to do it. Alternatively, you can emulate the functionality of a TabView and show your own custom tab bar. In this case, a simple ZStack with a switch statement can be used to switch between the subviews. Something like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewSwitcher()
    }
}

enum SubviewType {
    case main
    case transfers
    case crypto
}

struct ViewSwitcher: View {
    @State private var selectedSubview = SubviewType.transfers

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                switch selectedSubview {
                case .main: MainView()
                case .transfers: TransfersView()
                case .crypto: CryptoView()
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            BottomDockView(selectedSubview: $selectedSubview)
        }
    }
}

struct TransfersView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TransferView")
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("MainView")
    }
}

struct CryptoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("CryptoView")
    }
}

struct BottomDockView: View {
    @Binding var selectedSubview: SubviewType

    private func dockButton(symbolName: String, target: SubviewType) -> some View {
        Image(systemName: symbolName)
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium, design: .default))
            .symbolVariant(selectedSubview == target ? .fill : .none)
            .foregroundStyle(selectedSubview == target ? .black : .gray)
            .onTapGesture { selectedSubview = target }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            dockButton(symbolName: "house", target: .main)
            dockButton(symbolName: "arrow.left.arrow.right", target: .transfers)
            dockButton(symbolName: "bitcoinsign", target: .crypto)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 50)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(.gray.opacity(0.4))
    }
}



you're my savior, love u bro
